# Wraps or gloves for speed bag training?

Tags: boxing, gloves

I always did my speed bag training with wraps and never had a problem, but they are kind of a hassle to deal with in between workouts.  I recently saw some [speed bag gloves](http://store.titleboxing.com/speed-bag-gloves.html) which seem like an ideal solution.  Other than the fact that they might be more expensive, is there any downside to using gloves over wraps for speed bag-only workouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Speed bag work is non-injurious; wraps provide more wrist support, unnecessary on the speed bag. You might lose a tiny bit of mobility depending on the gloves.